# searching if arr is in a binary file c

Tags: c, file, malloc, arr

I have a project; a kind of a anti-virus, to search whether a virus is in a file.  My idea was to get a length of the virus and jump by one every time I reach the the length but I don't know how to do it exactly.

```
    int virusChaek(FILE* file, char virus[],char filesNames[], int len)
    {
        char* pch;
        int sizeOfFile = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int arr[100] = {0};
        int* myArr;
        int isVirus = 0;


        file = fopen(filesNames, "rb");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("file does not exist.");
            return 1;
        }
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        sizeOfFile = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        myArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * strlen(virus));
        while (0 < (sizeOfFile))
        {
            fread(arr, 1, 1, file);
            printf("arr[0] = %d\n", arr[0]);
    
            myArr[i] = arr[0];
            printf("myArr = %d\n", myArr[i]);
   
    
            sizeOfFile--;
            i++;
        }
        free(myArr);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to compare `virus` and `myArr`

Comment: Are `virus` really an array of int? I would expect an array of (unsigned) char

Comment: If you can't explain exactly what you intend the program to do there's very little hope you'll be able to code it.

Comment: my program just gets a file and Checks if it got a virus not somthing big if it found then returns 1 if nor then 0

Comment: Why do you make `myArr` an array of `int` when `virus` is an array of `char`?

Comment: `fread(arr, 1, 1, file);` what do you expect this to do?

Comment: You are doing `strlen(virus)` hmm... is `virus` a string? Maybe you should have use the parameter `len` !?

Comment: `file` is not a passed argument, it's a local variable. The base type of `sizeOfFile`, `arr` and `myArr` is `char`, not `int`. Why does `arr` have 100 elements, if you only use the first? Also, try and use a decent text syntax...

Comment: Take one step back and try to implement searching for a known string in a longer string. When that works think about what you need to do in order to look for a known sequence of binary bytes in a binary file.